# GITHUB how to set a rule, that will allow push only from master branch (to deploy branch)

Tags: github, branch, git-branch, rules

Sorry for asking question, thas is maybe answered somewhere else.
My problem is that i have branch for deployment and i want to set a rule, that will allow only push from master (where we have always working code) -> so nobody would push from their branch to deploy